# Convergence in distribution of this random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ indipendent random variables such that:

P($X_n$ $\in \mathbb {1,-n^2}) = 1$ and $E[X_n]=-1$ for each $n$.

It follows that:

$P(X_n=1) = (n^2-1)/(n^2+1)$,

$P(X_n=-n^2) = 2/(n^2+1)$

Let now $S_n:=X_1 + ... + X_n$

Does $S_n$ converges in distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum P(X_n=-n^{2}) =\sum \frac 2 {n^{2}+1}<\infty$. By Borel- Cantelli Lemma this implies that $X_n =1$ for all large $n$ with probability $1$. Hence $S_n \to \infty$ almost surely.